# mostrar datos solo por fecha mas reciente

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

estoy haciendo la siguiente consulta(contenida en una view) en sql server 2008

```
 SELECT
    arts.id_articulo,
    arts.estatus,
    arts.name,
    arts.des,
    arts.marca,
    arts.modelo,
    arts.anio,
    arts.version,
    arts.linea,
    arts.serie,
    arts.color,
    arts.avaluo,
    arts.cant_prestamo,
    cat.name AS categoria,
    conAr.f_cantidad,
    conAr.f_comxventa,
    conAr.precio_fijado,
    conAr.f_interes,
    conAr.f_almacenaje,
    conAr.f_remanente,
    cons.id_contrato AS ncontrato,
    cons.contrato_base AS etiqueta,
    cons.fecha_contrato,
    cons.fecha_vencimiento,
    cte.id_cliente,
    cte.nombre + ' ' + cte.ap_paterno+ ' ' + cte.ap_materno AS cliente,
    cte.tel,
    cons.interes,
    cons.int_almacenaje,
    cons.por_int,
    cons.por_almacenaje,
    rec.fecha 
FROM
    articulos arts
    JOIN cat_categorias cat ON cat.id = arts.id_cat
    JOIN articulo_contrato conAr ON conAr.id_articulo = arts.id_articulo
    JOIN contrato cons ON cons.id_contrato = conAr.id_contrato
    JOIN clientes cte ON cons.id_cliente = cte.id_cliente
    LEFT JOIN recibos rec ON cons.id_contrato = rec.id_contrato
```

y el resultado es este:
[image: resultado de consulta]

la duda que tengo es : ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que no me muestre datos duplicados? puesto que solo quiero mostrar los que tengan la fecha_contrato más reciente.

Comment: ¿Que versión de SQL Server usas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma mas "SQL ANSI compatible" es agregar un subconsulta para obtener la fecha máxima de contrato por `id_contrato` y usar la misma para filtrar estos registros, algo así:

```
SELECT arts.id_articulo,
       cons.id_contrato,
       cons.fecha_contrato
       FROM articulos arts
       INNER JOIN cat_categorias cat 
             ON cat.id = arts.id_cat
       INNER JOIN articulo_contrato conAr 
             ON conAr.id_articulo = arts.id_articulo
       INNER JOIN contrato cons 
             ON cons.id_contrato = conAr.id_contrato
       INNER JOIN clientes cte 
             ON cons.id_cliente = cte.id_cliente
       
       INNER JOIN (SELECT id_contrato,
                          MAX(fecha_contrato) as fecha_max
                          FROM contrato
                          GROUP BY id_contrato
                  ) ULT
                  ULT.id_contrato = cons.id_contrato
                  AND ULT.fecha_max = cons.fecha_contrato
                          
       LEFT JOIN recibos rec 
            ON cons.id_contrato = rec.id_contrato
```

NOTA: Quite todas tus columnas para que el código sea más compacto y claro.

Otra forma, incluso mejor, siempre que la versión de SQL Server te lo permita es hacer algo así:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT arts.id_articulo,
       cons.id_contrato,
       cons.fecha_contrato,
       row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY cons.id_contrato ORDER BY fecha_contrato desc) as rn
       FROM articulos arts
       INNER JOIN cat_categorias cat 
             ON cat.id = arts.id_cat
       INNER JOIN articulo_contrato conAr 
             ON conAr.id_articulo = arts.id_articulo
       INNER JOIN contrato cons 
             ON cons.id_contrato = conAr.id_contrato
       INNER JOIN clientes cte 
             ON cons.id_cliente = cte.id_cliente
       LEFT JOIN recibos rec 
            ON cons.id_contrato = rec.id_contrato
 )
 SELECT id_articulo,
        id_contrato,
        fecha_contrato
        FROM CTE
        WHERE rn = 1
```

Usamos (a) una [CTE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) para materializar una columna de numeración de filas y (b) [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) para generar un numerador por particionado por el contrato y con un orden descendente por fecha del mismo